# When do i use an definite or indefinite article instead of nothing after the word "of"?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, articles

I hear it's not correct to use an indefinite article after "of". But i don't know exactly in which cases it's correct and in which not.

And also, maybe it doesn't only apply to the word "of". Maybe there are other words like that after which people don't use articles.

The question is: when do i use an article, and when not, when it comes to such 
a word as "of"?

And also, do i use it correctly in this sentence?

> Search by the name of a form of study

Comment: Perhaps you mean *indefinite* or *definite* article? And the sentence is fine with the indefinite article as you have it.

Comment: Ok, I edited the question. 
You're saying that my question is fine - alright, that's good. But why would it be incorrect if the sentence were "search by the name of a form of a study"?

Comment: Because the indefinite article in *that* instance makes it refer to a specific study—something published in a scientific journal, perhaps—not the general concept of *study*, and in that case you've already used a specifier: "a form of ..." You want *study* to refer to a class, not an instance of a class.

Comment: "I hear it's not correct" isn't helpful. A more substantial starting point would be nice. Anyway, article use is tied to the noun following it, not a preposition or word before it.

Answer (score 1):

As User3169 commented, "article use is tied to the noun following it, not a preposition or word before it." The standard rules of articles apply in all cases.

In your example, "study" refers generally to the concept, just as "research" would. If "study" were referring to a specific study, then "the study" would be correct. If "study" were referring to any single study out of many possible studies, then "a study" would be correct.